# PPP / 3G modem not getting an IP: No network protocols running

Tags: serial, modem, point-to-point-protocol, 3g, gsm

Modem in use: SIM5310 connected to an ARM based board.

```
root@cm-debian:~# uname -a
Linux cm-debian 4.4.0-cm-t335-5.1-00030-gd350d89-dirty #29 SMP Sat Nov 4 19:18:48 PDT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I am initializing the chat using minicom for now and not using a script.

using AT commands I could see that there is an IP address assigned

```
at+cgpaddr
+CGPADDR: 1,"176.13.98.14"
+CGPADDR: 2,"0.0.0.0"
```

AT ping to 8.8.8.8 also works:

```
at+cping="8.8.8.8",1
OK
+STIN: 25
+STIN: 25
+CPING: 1,8.8.8.8,64,484,255
+CPING: 1,8.8.8.8,64,394,255
+CPING: 1,8.8.8.8,64,392,255
+CPING: 1,8.8.8.8,64,771,255
+CPING: 3,4,4,0,392,771,510
```

more at info:

```
at+cgatt?    
+CGATT: 1# packet domain attached

at+cgact?  
+CGACT: 1,1 # PDP context is activated
+CGACT: 2,0

ati
Manufacturer: SIMCOM INCORPORATED
Model: SIMCOM_SIM5310
Revision: SIM5310_V1.5
IMEI: 359768030163686
+GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+ES
```

here's what pppd outputs

```
 root@cm-debian:~# pppd -detach noauth  noipdefault debug usepeerdns /dev/ttyO1 115200 ipcp-accept-local ipcp-accept-remote
    using channel 36
    Using interface ppp0
    Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyO1
    sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4748d05c> <pcomp> <accomp>]
    rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x50 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x15c05db> <pcomp> <accomp>]
    No auth is possible
    sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x50 <auth pap>]
    rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x4748d05c> <pcomp> <accomp>]
    rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x51 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x15c05db> <pcomp> <accomp>]
    sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x51 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x15c05db> <pcomp> <accomp>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x52 magic=0x15c05db]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
    IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
    sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]
    sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]
    Connection terminated.
    Modem hangup
```

trying with a pap blank user/pass authentication:

```
root@cm-debian:~# pppd -detach user "" password "" noipdefault debug usepeerdns /dev/ttyO1 115200 ipcp-accept-local ipcp-accept-remote
using channel 37
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyO1
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x9300f3d> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x53 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x15fa3e3> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x53 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x15fa3e3> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x9300f3d> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="" password=<hidden>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x54 magic=0x15fa3e3]
rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
PAP authentication succeeded
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

disabling header compression etc:

```
root@cm-debian:~# pppd -detach user "" password "" novj noccp novjccomp noipdefault debug usepeerdns /dev/ttyO1 115200 ipcp-accept-local ipcp-accept-remote
using channel 38
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyO1
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x670e49b4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x55 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x161ece0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x55 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x161ece0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x670e49b4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="" password=<hidden>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x56 magic=0x161ece0]
rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
PAP authentication succeeded
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

UPDTE:

I could get ms-wins IP addresses using the following attributes:
NOTE: this happens occasionally, mostly returning 0.0.0.0 wins addresses

```
root@cm-debian:~# pppd -detach user "" password ""  debug usepeerdns /dev/ttyO1 115200
using channel 52
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyO1
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x6f1654a4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x76 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x18a9792> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x76 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0x18a9792> <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x6f1654a4> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="" password=<hidden>]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x77 magic=0x18a9792]
rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
PAP authentication succeeded
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting an APN in your chat script, e.g. like this? 'OK'    'ATE0V1&D2&C1S0=0+IFC=2,2'
        'OK'    'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","3ireland.ie"'

Comment: yes, at+cgdcont=? returns 1,"IP","internetg" as its already set. but this doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "sphone" in at+cgdcont works instead of "internetg"